# How to clear a material-ui search input using a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, use-state

Working on a tutorial atm that involves react material-ui tables that also has a search input textfield. What I am trying to add to it, is a button that will reset the table report but also clear the search input textfield.

It is the clearing of the search textfield that I am having trouble with.

They are using this code as a separate component library called Controls.input:

import React from 'react'
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';

```
export default function Input(props) {

    const { name, label, value,error=null, onChange, ...other } = props;
    return (
        <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            label={label}
            name={name}
            value={value}
            onChange={onChange}
            {...other}
            {...(error && {error:true,helperText:error})}
        />
    )
}
```

The main search code is as follows where I have also added a button

```
            <Controls.Input
                id="name"
                label="Search Name"
                className={classes.searchInput}
                InputProps={{
                    startAdornment: (<InputAdornment position="start">
                        <Search />
                    </InputAdornment>)
                }}
                onChange={handleSearch}
            />
            <Button
                onClick={handleClear}
                className="materialBtn"
            >
                Clear
            </Button>
```

At this point, I am not sure how to reference/target the search input field as part of the `handleClear` function, in-order to clear it's contents?

```
const handleClear = () => {
    ????
}
```

Do I need to use `useState()`?

Comment: You will have to clear the value of text input. You can useState to keep the value and clear it in handleClear function .

Comment: @BhaskarJoshi - sorry, how can I access the value of the text input inorder to use useState?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69257278/how-to-append-a-button-to-textfield-in-material-ui

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right with having to put the value into state. Based on what you have supplied it seems that your state needs to be in your parent component. So something like this should work

```js
import { useState } from 'react'

const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')

    const handleClear = () => {
        setValue('')
    }

    const handleSearch = (event) => {
        setValue(event.target.value)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Controls.Input
                id="name"
                label="Search Name"
                className={classes.searchInput}
                value={value}
                onChange={handleSearch}
                InputProps={{
                    startAdornment: (
                        <InputAdornment position="start">
                            <Search />
                        </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                }}
                
            />
            <Button onClick={handleClear} className="materialBtn">
                Clear
            </Button>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Seem to have an issue with the `value={value}` as this is not allowing me to enter any value into my search input field, just stays null. Any ideas pls?

Comment: I did a small edit on the answer. But the reason you cant enter anything is because now the value is coming from the value state. So what you need to do is make sure that the onChange is working correctly. I would recommend removing the ```value={value}``` line on the input component first and put a console.log in the handleSearch function to make sure that a value is being changed